# Linear Transformation of Matrix Representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If $$ A = \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & -1 & 2 \\
        -2 & 1 & -1 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{matrix}
\right] $$ is the matrix representation of a linear transformation  $$T :P_2(x) \to P_2(x)$$ with respect to the bases $\{1-x, x(1-x), x(1+x)\}$ and $\{1, 1+x, 1+ x^2\}$ then find T.
What is the procedure to solve it? Also which book I can refer for more examples like this?

Comment: To begin with, do you know what it means for $A$ to be the matrix of $T$ with respect to a pair of bases?

Comment: @amd I know how to calculate matrix representation of a linear transformation if basis are given but not the other way around. Also, the book I am using (Schaum's Outline), there is not a single example of this type. Help!

Comment: The columns of the matrix of a transformation are the images of the basis vectors of the domain expressed relative to the basis of the codomain, i.e., it specifies a linear combination of the codomain basis vectors. So, the first column of $A$ tells us that $T[1-x]=1\cdot(1)-2\cdot(1+x)+1\cdot(1+x^2)=x^2-2x$, and so on. From that, you should be able to work out what $T$ does to the general polynomial $a+bx+cx^2$. Alternatively, you might convert $A$ to the standard basis and read the solution from that.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the the matrix of a transformation has as its columns the images of the domain basis vectors expressed relative to a basis of the codomain. Assuming that the first of the given bases is for the domain, this means that $$T[1-x] = 1\cdot(1)-2\cdot(1+x)+1\cdot(1+x^2) = x^2-2x.$$ The other two columns give you $T[x(1-x)]$ and $T[x(1+x)]$, respectively. Now, express the general second-degree polynomial $a+bx+cx^2$ as a linear combination of the domain basis polynomials, i.e., as $\alpha(1-x)+\beta x(1-x)+\gamma x(1+x)$ and use linearity of $T$: $$T[a+bx+cy]=\alpha T[1-x]+\beta T[x(1-x)]+\gamma T[x(1+x)].$$ Collect terms in the resulting polynomial, and you’re done.

Alternatively, apply a change of basis to $A$ to express it relative to the standard basis $(1,x,x^2)$ for both domain and codomain. On the codomain (output) side, we want to map *from* the given basis *to* the standard basis. This can be accomplished by multiplying by a matrix that has the given basis vectors as its columns. On the domain (input) side, we want to map *from* the standard basis *to* the given basis, which can be done by multiplying by the *inverse* of the matrix with the given basis vectors for its columns. The columns of the resulting matrix give you $T[1]$, $T[x]$ and $T[x^2]$, from which it is an easy matter to construct $T[a+bx+cx^2]$.